# PHP preg_replace for hex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to use `preg_replace()` to remove all hexadecimal characters in a string (with only lower case letters):

```
$line = "sjdivfriyaaqa\xd2vkmpcuyyuen";
$line = preg_replace('/\\x[0-9a-f]{2}/', '', $line);
echo($line);
```

This should, as I understand it, echo `sjdivfriyaaqavkmpcuyyuen` (`$line` with `\xd2` removed) but it echoes the original `$line`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
$line = "sjdivfriyaaqa\\xd2vkmpcuyyuen";
$new = preg_replace('/\\\x[0-9a-f]{2}/', '', $line);
echo($new);
```

You need another blackslash to escape it in the string, if you try echoing it right away you will see that it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the double quotes `""` interpretes escaped char `\` meaning `"\xd2"` is `'Ò'` for instance.

Using simple quote  `''` your code is ok:

```
$line = 'sjdivfriyaaqa\xd2vkmpcuyyuen';
$line = preg_replace('#\\\x[0-9a-f]{2}#', '', $line);
echo($line);
```

Comment: btw why three backslashes ? ```\\\``` => two \\ results to the real ```\``` char, the third means the char is escaped, four \ will be ok too.